# Python regular expression to insert "." after first two characters of a string

Tags: python, regex

Given: `"2276514"`

Expected: `"22.76514"`

Please explain how it works.

Comment: Don't need `regex`. You can use simple string methods for this

Comment: ya got solution through st[:2]+"."+st[2:10] way but i need some customization

Comment: As i had lot of strings which needs to do the same hence i need that to be done in regx

Comment: Try `newst = st[:2] + '.' + st[2:]`

Comment: Thanks for the correction but as i have huge set of data where i wouls not be able to assign variables and do it . I though regx would be a better way to do

Comment: May i know what is the performance with respect to string processing or in regex ? would be same !

Comment: @HarishTM if performance is really crucial, try both and `timeit` to find out. You could also consider a numerical method, if you need the actual float: `int(s) / (10 ** (len(s) - 2))`.

Comment: @HarishTM You didn't mention performance in your question.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: "please write some code for me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much easier to slice and concatenate but if you want a regex:

```
s= "2276514"
import re
print(re.sub("(\w{2})",r"\1.",s,1))
```

`\w{2}` looks for exactly 2 alphanumeric characters, `r"\1."` uses the capture group adding a period to the end as the replace value, `s` is obviously the string to replace and `1` is how many substitutions to make.

Slicing is a lot more efficient:

```
In [37]: s*= 1000

In [38]: timeit s[:2]+"."+s[2:]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 860 ns per loop

In [39]: timeit r.sub(r"\1.",s,1)
 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.73 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution problem is solved but can u explain 2nd and third argument

Comment: and may i know the performance when i use regx and normal string processing

Answer (score 0):

Using the following test script:

```
import re

def string(s):
    return '{}.{}'.format(s[:2], s[2:])

def regex(s):
    return re.sub(r'^(\d{2})', r'\1.', s)

def numerical(s):
    return str(int(s) / (10 ** (len(s) - 2)))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from textwrap import dedent
    from timeit import timeit

    funcs = ('string', 'regex', 'numerical')
    test = '{}(s)'
    setup = dedent('''
        from __main__ import {}
        s = "2276514"
        assert {}
        '''.format(
            ', '.join(funcs),
            ' == '.join(test.format(func) for func in funcs),
        )
    )
    for func in funcs:
        print(func, timeit(test.format(func), setup=setup))
```

It turns out that using a regular expression is much less efficient than doing the maths or just slicing the string:

```
string 0.913286265126315
regex 8.614692108100677
numerical 2.954279778595833
```

If you actually want the number (i.e. adding `float` to the first two and removing `str` from the last one), then the numerical method is fastest:

```
string 1.449586457505659
regex 9.255363527420872
numerical 0.9225037999760559
```

Either way, regex loses; you can save a bit of time by pre-compiling the pattern (e.g. put `pattern=re.compile(r'^(\d{2})')` as a default argument and use `pattern.sub(r'\1.', s)` in the function), but not enough to make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: @HarishTM http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: What about `'.'.join((s[:2], s[2:]))` ? ;)

Comment: @sebastian very slightly faster than the current `string`, but still doesn't beat `numerical` in the second case.